# Installation for PyJNIus - PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acess denied

Tags: python, pip, pyjnius

I have tried the following measures, but error still pops up

- Run the cmd in administrator role
- Set myself as pycham and python files in administrator role
- Used pip install --user PyJNIus
- Used python -m pip install --user PyJNIus
- Closed Pycham, and run cmd in administrator role
- I am already having the highest access right for all files

Can anyone help me out?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --user PyJNIus
Collecting PyJNIus
  Using cached pyjnius-1.2.1.tar.gz (40 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ueh9n_76\\PyJNIus\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ueh9n_76\\PyJNIus\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueh9n_76\PyJNIus\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueh9n_76\PyJNIus\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueh9n_76\PyJNIus\setup.py", line 92, in <module>
        compile_native_invocation_handler(*get_possible_homes(PLATFORM))
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ueh9n_76\PyJNIus\setup.py", line 82, in compile_native_invocation_handler
        subprocess.check_call([
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 359, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acess denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem too. Try upgrade your python into 64-bit, it works for me.